# PhP - SQL Query, Variable moves to the end of the Query

Tags: php, sql, variables, quotes

I have a query that I would like to run to input data into my MySQL database. It is working fine with pure text and numbers, but inputting variables in:

```
$base_ids = 4;
while($j <= $base_ids){
$row = array(keygenb());

foreach($row as $value){
$query = "INSERT INTO webstore(col_1) VALUES('".$value."')";
echo $query;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
$j++;
}
```

When I echo $query, there is a problem with the VALUES('".$value."')"; 
Echoing $query gives me this:
($value = XBox-CJbf-Ont4-B7kk)

```
INSERT INTO webstore(col_1) VALUES('')XBox-CJbf-Ont4-B7kk
```

The $value gets stuck on the end, rather than put between the quotes where it can be executed.
I'm sure this is an easy fix, however I've tried to get around it a few ways and haven't yet found a way that works.

Many thanks,

Mem

Comment: Use escaping for all data that is passed to a query. mysqli_real_escape_string will do the thing

Comment: Are you sure? because I tried and it works alright for me..

Comment: I believe so - I've tried to use plain text or numbers and that inputs into my database without issues. I changed it to:

$query = "INSERT INTO webstore(col_1) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$value)."')";

I'm getting the same result for my echo statement and nothing in the database. :x

Comment: Escaping is also a good idea for security reasons.  Even if the query works, it may be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200256/how-can-i-avoid-sql-injection-attacks).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will use it in future :)

Comment: When passing php variable to a query, no concatenation is necessary: `$query="INSERT INTO webstore(col_1) VALUES('$value')";` is correct syntax.

Comment: Yea, I was going to suggest what jegesh suggested. See what happens when you do that. I've never seen that bug before. However, jegesh, that's not necessarily the correct syntax for an sql query, that is just how PHP works. If you use double quotes, you can put the variables right into any string and it'll replace it with the string variable you put in. If he had used single quotes to form his query, he would have had to concatenate. Just letting anyone who reads this, know what's really going on.

Comment: That must have been what was wrong, it's working for me now. Thanks jegesh and Omar.